# Files not visible on a Juptyer Notebook on Azure Machine Learning Studio Instance and subsequent timeout

Tags: azure, azure-machine-learning-service

I'm referring to some docs and tutorials for the Azure DP-100 Exam related to Data Science.

On creating a Compute Instance (STANDARD_DS11_V2), I opened the Jupyter notebook, and cloned a sample repository (https://github.com/microsoftdocs/ml-basics)

[image]

After this, I'm not able to load or see the files inside the ml-basics folder on Jupyter.

Nothing happens on clicking on ml-basics folder, apart from the below error message after a long wait -

*Timed out attempting to connect to this compute instance.
Check to make sure the compute instance is started. If you just started it, try again in a minute or two.*

Answer (score 0):

I'm not able to reproduce this issue, works fine for me. As mentioned in the error message, ensure your instance is up and running. If it is, try restarting it and also ensure there are no firewalls blocking your connection.

[image]